# Java regex how to find the parent match?

Tags: java, regex, string, match, wikipedia

Any page from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org):

```
...
abas asdn asf asfs af
{{Template1
|a = Name surname
|b = jhsdf sdf
|c = {{Template2}}
|d = 
|e = [[f]] and [[g]]
|h = asd asdasfgasgasg asgas jygh trdx dftf xcth
|i = 73
|j = {{Template2|abc|123}}
|j = {{Template3|aa=kkk|bb={{Template4|cc=uu}}}}
}}

asd wetd gdsgwew g

{{OtherTemplate
|sdf = 213
}}
...
```

How can i find `Template1`'s content (start is `|a` end is `}}`) with Java regexes?

I tried:

```
String pattern = "\\{\\{\\s*Template1\\s*(.*?)\\}\\}";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(content);

while (m.find()) {
    if (!m.group().equals("")) {
        System.out.println(m.group());
        System.out.println("-----------------------");
    }
}
```

But in here the regex is finding the first `}}` (which is `Template2` `}}`) then stops.
I want to pass `}}` is any `{{` is open. Then I want to find top parent match.

I want to get top `Template1` content between top `{{` and `}}`?.

**EDIT:**

Please keep in mind that I am parsing `content` after removing white spaces.

```
content.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Think of content as writing a single line.

Comment: Use `Jsoup` api. Simpler than writing regex

Comment: It is strongly advised against to use regular expressions to parse markup, or anything with a hierarchical grammar. Use your own parser or any available product (see also TheLostMind's comment).

Comment: @TheLostMind isn't jsoup HTML parser? How can i parse "{{" with "jsoup"

Comment: @Kumul - You can get tags and seperate data

Comment: What is consistent between parent templates? What I'm trying to get at is what signifies the start of a parent template (that is different from child templates). In order to solve your problem, we need to identify the breakpoint to match against. Also, why do you strip all the whitespace? As it can help to find a breakpoint...

Comment: OK, I think I understand now. Looking at wikipedia pages, the source is a complete mess to read. I'll have a think about it and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

`/^{{Template1(.*?)^}}/sm`

returns:

```
|a = Name surname
|b = jhsdf sdf
|c = {{Template2}}
|d = 
|e = [[f]] and [[g]]
|h = asd asdasfgasgasg asgas jygh trdx dftf xcth
|i = 73
|j = {{Template2|abc|123}}
|j = {{Template3|aa=kkk|bb={{Template4|cc=uu}}}}
```

https://regex101.com/r/qC6cM1/1 (DEMO)

Comment: It's not working when remove the whitespaces when change line to "|j = {{Template3|aa=kkk|bb={{Template4|cc=uu}}}}}}"

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying - what about whitespace?

Comment: When you move "Template1" closing tag "}}" to end of "|j" line this regex not working. (whitespace: When you remove all newlines, make single line all of content)

Comment: this not working because the text not exactly that i wrote look at this: https://regex101.com/r/qC6cM1/4

Comment: You keep changing the output of the text you want to match! Please decide how exactly it should look like.

Comment: You don't understood the main question. Wikipedia pages are dynamical changing so there is no exactly page in wikipedia. Somebody using whitespace somebody not using. So i edited my question. I think question is clear now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87265/discussion-between-trung-nguyen-and-kumul).

Answer (score 0):

```
\\{\\{\\s*Template1\\s*(.*?)\\n\\}\\}

                        ^^
```

Just include `\n`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/72

Comment: It is not work when the last line is |j = {{Template3|aa=kkk|bb={{Template4|cc=uu}}}}}}

Answer (score 0):

I think parser would do better jub in this case, but if you want regex, how about this one:

```
{{Template1(?:[^{}]*?(?:{{[^}]+?}}))+(?:[}\n\s]+})*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eL5fR0/2)

I assumed that your input is like single line.

Comment: this is not working when last }} move to newline: Like: https://regex101.com/r/eL5fR0/3

Comment: @Kumul and this one: [demo](https://regex101.com/r/eL5fR0/4). it is changed a little bit

Comment: hey it is looking good. I am trying for bugs. If its work without bug i will accept answer. Give me some time for tries.

Comment: @m.celiera when add space before }} its not working: https://regex101.com/r/eL5fR0/5

Comment: emm is it possible to stop when last }} find. So in wikipedi pages user can write extra }} like this: https://regex101.com/r/eL5fR0/7

Comment: @Kumul regex is not eficient in matching nested brackets, it cannot count them so I am afraid it is not possible, or at least a don't know answer.

Comment: Ok i understand that parsing the context is more easier than write regex. Can you update your main answer to your last regex? i will accept it soon if i not found better that this.